# Nginx+daphne WebSocket connect doesn't receive

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I use nginx as reverse proxy for daphne to use django channels.

Here's my nginx.conf

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name <ip_addr>;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                        proxy_redirect     off;
                        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                }
        }
```

in daphne's log:

```
2017-07-17 08:45:35,011 DEBUG    WebSocket daphne.response.xxx open and established
2017-07-17 08:45:35,011 DEBUG    WebSocket daphne.response.xxx accepted by application
```

but WebSocket's connect in client side doesn't receive any message

Can you help me?

UPDATE:

client-side code (I use Starscream library for WebSocket connection in Swift):

```
socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://site/proxy?token="+token!)!)

func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
        print("websocket is connected")
}

socket.connect()
```

routing.py:

```
channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", 'project.consumers.ws_message'),
    route("websocket.connect", 'project.consumers.ws_connect'),
]
```

consumers.py:

```
@rest_token_user
def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
```

res_user from: https://gist.github.com/leonardoo/9574251b3c7eefccd84fc38905110ce4

Comment: Can you share your client side code?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid added client-side code. I think problem is that nginx doesn't receive accept message, but I don't know how to solve it ((

Comment: And how does your `routing` look?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid added

Comment: I am not familiar with StarScream, does that function attach to the `onopen` event of the `socket` somehow?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid yes. It works earlier

Comment: having same problem here. must be nginx configuration issue. did you solve yours?